# I cannot install any application in Fedora using the dnf command

Tags: fedora, chrome, repository, dnf

I want to install Chrome on my Fedora. I downloaded the file and ran the following command:

```
sudo dnf localinstall google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm -y
```

But I got this error message:

```
Warning: failed loading '/etc/yum.repos.d/skype-stable.repo', skipping.
Fedora 37 openh264 (From Cisco) - x86_64                                                                                                0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:26    
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'fedora-cisco-openh264':
  - Curl error (7): Couldn't connect to server for https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=fedora-cisco-openh264-37&arch=x86_64 [Failed to connect to mirrors.fedoraproject.org port 443 after 2176 ms: Connection refused]
  - Curl error (7): Couldn't connect to server for https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=fedora-cisco-openh264-37&arch=x86_64 [Failed to connect to mirrors.fedoraproject.org port 443 after 2486 ms: Connection refused]
  - Curl error (7): Couldn't connect to server for https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=fedora-cisco-openh264-37&arch=x86_64 [Failed to connect to mirrors.fedoraproject.org port 443 after 2137 ms: Connection refused]
  - Curl error (7): Couldn't connect to server for https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=fedora-cisco-openh264-37&arch=x86_64 [Failed to connect to mirrors.fedoraproject.org port 443 after 2162 ms: Connection refused]
  - Curl error (7): Couldn't connect to server for https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=fedora-cisco-openh264-37&arch=x86_64 [Failed to connect to mirrors.fedoraproject.org port 443 after 2377 ms: Connection refused]
  - Curl error (7): Couldn't connect to server for https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=fedora-cisco-openh264-37&arch=x86_64 [Failed to connect to mirrors.fedoraproject.org port 443 after 2284 ms: Connection refused]
  - Curl error (7): Couldn't connect to server for https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=fedora-cisco-openh264-37&arch=x86_64 [Failed to connect to mirrors.fedoraproject.org port 443 after 2268 ms: Connection refused]
  - Curl error (7): Couldn't connect to server for https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=fedora-cisco-openh264-37&arch=x86_64 [Failed to connect to mirrors.fedoraproject.org port 443 after 2177 ms: Connection refused]
  - Curl error (7): Couldn't connect to server for https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=fedora-cisco-openh264-37&arch=x86_64 [Failed to connect to mirrors.fedoraproject.org port 443 after 2205 ms: Connection refused]
  - Curl error (7): Couldn't connect to server for https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=fedora-cisco-openh264-37&arch=x86_64 [Failed to connect to mirrors.fedoraproject.org port 443 after 2186 ms: Connection refused]
  - Curl error (7): Couldn't connect to server for https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=fedora-cisco-openh264-37&arch=x86_64 [Failed to connect to mirrors.fedoraproject.org port 443 after 2158 ms: Connection refused]
  - Curl error (7): Couldn't connect to server for https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=fedora-cisco-openh264-37&arch=x86_64 [Failed to connect to mirrors.fedoraproject.org port 443 after 2224 ms: Connection refused]
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'fedora-cisco-openh264': Cannot prepare internal mirrorlist: Curl error (7): Couldn't connect to server for https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=fedora-cisco-openh264-37&arch=x86_64 [Failed to connect to mirrors.fedoraproject.org port 443 after 2177 ms: Connection refused]
Fedora Modular 37 - x86_64 - Updates                                                                                                    0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:27    
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'updates-modular':
  - Curl error (7): Couldn't connect to server for https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=updates-released-modular-f37&arch=x86_64 [Failed to connect to mirrors.fedoraproject.org port 443 after 2623 ms: Connection refused]
  - Curl error (7): Couldn't connect to server for https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=updates-released-modular-f37&arch=x86_64 [Failed to connect to mirrors.fedoraproject.org port 443 after 2611 ms: Connection refused]
  - Curl error (7): Couldn't connect to server for https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=updates-released-modular-f37&arch=x86_64 [Failed to connect to mirrors.fedoraproject.org port 443 after 2217 ms: Connection refused]
  - Curl error (7): Couldn't connect to server for https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=updates-released-modular-f37&arch=x86_64 [Failed to connect to mirrors.fedoraproject.org port 443 after 2159 ms: Connection refused]
  - Curl error (7): Couldn't connect to server for https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=updates-released-modular-f37&arch=x86_64 [Failed to connect to mirrors.fedoraproject.org port 443 after 2155 ms: Connection refused]
  - Curl error (7): Couldn't connect to server for https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=updates-released-modular-f37&arch=x86_64 [Failed to connect to mirrors.fedoraproject.org port 443 after 2170 ms: Connection refused]
  - Curl error (7): Couldn't connect to server for https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=updates-released-modular-f37&arch=x86_64 [Failed to connect to mirrors.fedoraproject.org port 443 after 2153 ms: Connection refused]
  - Curl error (7): Couldn't connect to server for https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=updates-released-modular-f37&arch=x86_64 [Failed to connect to mirrors.fedoraproject.org port 443 after 2193 ms: Connection refused]
  - Curl error (7): Couldn't connect to server for https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=updates-released-modular-f37&arch=x86_64 [Failed to connect to mirrors.fedoraproject.org port 443 after 2335 ms: Connection refused]
  - Curl error (7): Couldn't connect to server for https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=updates-released-modular-f37&arch=x86_64 [Failed to connect to mirrors.fedoraproject.org port 443 after 2191 ms: Connection refused]
  - Curl error (7): Couldn't connect to server for https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=updates-released-modular-f37&arch=x86_64 [Failed to connect to mirrors.fedoraproject.org port 443 after 2237 ms: Connection refused]
  - Curl error (7): Couldn't connect to server for https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=updates-released-modular-f37&arch=x86_64 [Failed to connect to mirrors.fedoraproject.org port 443 after 2235 ms: Connection refused]
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'updates-modular': Cannot prepare internal mirrorlist: Curl error (7): Couldn't connect to server for https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=updates-released-modular-f37&arch=x86_64 [Failed to connect to mirrors.fedoraproject.org port 443 after 2155 ms: Connection refused]
```

I tried changing baseurl in **/etc/yum.repos.d/fedora.repo** and still did not get any results. My location is in Iran and use proxy for connecting to the Internet.

The changes in fedora.repo file:

```
[fedora]
name=Fedora $releasever - $basearch
#baseurl=http://download.example/pub/fedora/linux/releases/$releasever/Everything/$basearch/os/
baseurl=http://na.edge.kernel.org/fedora/updates/37/Everything/x86_64/
#baseurl=http://centos.mirror.alwyzon.net/fedora/updates/37/Everything/x86_64/
#baseurl=https://na.edge.kernel.org/fedora/linux/releases/37/Everything/x86_64/
#baseurl=https://na.edge.kernel.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/$releasever/Everything/$basearch/os/
#baseurl=http://fedora.mirror.gtcomm.net/pub/fedora/linux/releases/$releasever/Everything/$basearch/os/
#metalink=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=fedora-$releasever&arch=$basearch
enabled=1
countme=1
metadata_expire=7d
repo_gpgcheck=0
type=rpm
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-fedora-$releasever-$basearch
skip_if_unavailable=False

[fedora-debuginfo]
name=Fedora $releasever - $basearch - Debug
#baseurl=http://download.example/pub/fedora/linux/releases/$releasever/Everything/$basearch/debug/tree/
baseurl=http://na.edge.kernel.org/fedora/updates/37/Everything/x86_64/
#baseurl=http://centos.mirror.alwyzon.net/fedora/updates/37/Everything/x86_64/
#baseurl=http://fedora.mirror.gtcomm.net/pub/fedora/linux/releases/$releasever/Everything/$basearch/os/
#baseurl=https://na.edge.kernel.org/fedora/linux/releases/37/Everything/x86_64/
#baseurl=https://na.edge.kernel.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/$releasever/Everything/$basearch/os/
#metalink=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=fedora-debug-$releasever&arch=$basearch
enabled=0
```